# how to store stringify json data into mongodb using C# MongoDB.Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, webapi, mongodb.driver

i am fetching data in strigify json format

```
"[{\"ApplytoAllYesNo\":\"\",\"PartNumber\":\"\",\"Description\":\"\",\"LotNumber\":\"\",\"Revision\":\"\",\"Comment\":\"\",\"QualStatus\":\"\",\"Upload\":\"\",\"buildID\":\"62161d4fee3776fba3d8b83e\"},{\"ApplytoAllYesNo\":\"\",\"PartNumber\":\"\",\"Description\":\"\",\"LotNumber\":\"\",\"Revision\":\"\",\"Comment\":\"\",\"QualStatus\":\"\",\"Upload\":\"\",\"buildID\":\"62161d4fee3776fba3d8b83e\"},{\"ApplytoAllYesNo\":\"\",\"PartNumber\":\"\",\"Description\":\"\",\"LotNumber\":\"\",\"Revision\":\"\",\"Comment\":\"\",\"QualStatus\":\"\",\"Upload\":\"\",\"buildID\":\"62161d4fee3776fba3d8b83e\"},{\"ApplytoAllYesNo\":\"\",\"PartNumber\":\"\",\"Description\":\"\",\"LotNumber\":\"\",\"Revision\":\"\",\"Comment\":\"\",\"QualStatus\":\"\",\"Upload\":\"\",\"buildID\":\"62161d4fee3776fba3d8b83e\"},{\"ApplytoAllYesNo\":\"\",\"PartNumber\":\"\",\"Description\":\"\",\"LotNumber\":\"\",\"Revision\":\"\",\"Comment\":\"\",\"QualStatus\":\"\",\"Upload\":\"\",\"buildID\":\"62161d4fee3776fba3d8b83e\"}]"
```

every time this data will change, that's why I am unable to use fixed model hear as my object won't have fixed number of columns, and number columns will change in each request, these columns created in front end.

I just want to insert json strigify data into mongoDB whatever it comes in that object.

```
[HttpPost("saveBuildData")]
    public async void saveBuildData(BuildSchema data)
    {            
        await _buildsService.insertBuildConfigData(data.buildData);            
    }

public async Task insertBuildConfigData(dynamic obj)
    {
        var connectionString = _configuration["DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString"];
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase("cascade");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("buildconfig_MATERIAL");
        var q = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(obj);
        await collection.InsertOneAsync(q);
    }
```

above code is not working and I am unable to insert the data into mongoDB.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTDif.png)

Comment: Add there error message you getting to your question.

Comment: asked user to add the error he is getting

Comment: Your JSON is an array, but you try to `InsertOne`. Maybe can check the result of deserializing that JSON to BsonDocument.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone looking for a solution to this problem. It worked for me when I changed
*`collection.InsertOne(q)`*
instead of
*`await collection.InsertOneAsync(q);`*

I am not claiming this is the best solution but it worked in my case, where I am only interested in uploading a json file to Mongodb collection using c#.